# getting error while encrypting aa already existed stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, encryption

I am trying to encrypt the stored procedure as below but its giving error.Please help me

```
alter procedure spo1
with encryption
@ID int,  
@NAME nvarchar(60)
as  
begin  
  insert into metal1 (id,name) values (@ID,@NAME)  
end
```

Comment: Please Show  error..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Wrote wrong  Syntax Please Check Below code..

```
  alter procedure spo1
     @ID int,
    @NAME nvarchar(60) 
     with encryption // Put With Encryption Here...
    as
    begin
    insert into metal1 (id,name) values (@ID,@NAME)
    end
```